# Disabling default keyboard on iPad with iOS 4.2

Tags: keyboard

I have enabled 3 languages and use their keyboards, but the default keyboard still insists on popping up. Bought in Bangkok, using in Europe.Can I disable this unnecessary keyboard or am I stuck with it??

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into `Settings -> General -> Keyboard`
2. Tap `Edit`
3. Tap and hold the "handle" (it looks like three horizontal bars) on English and drag it to the bottom

Or you can disable it outright.

Comment: Well, that did not work.it deleted the English kb ok, but NOT
 the default, which doesn't even show up in the settings...
Anybody??